# How to format a spark dataframe in to excel file with colours on basis of data and then write to a Azure storage

Tags: excel, pyspark, colors

Problem Statement is :- Data is structured table in Spark , you need to query it and convert into a format and write in xlsx file , with colour coding such as mandatory columns orange , optional columns yellow and the row where things are missing RED

there are different approaches , but it didn't work as style get loosed when you try to write

Tried converting spark dataframe did conditional formating and using BlockBlobService create_blob_from text trying to write but didnt worked

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
        from io import BytesIO
        from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
        
        blobService = BlockBlobService(account_name="storageaccountname", account_key="Storage Key",protocol='https')
        # sample = pd.DataFrame(sample_dict)
        sample = pd_data_df
        
        # Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
        
        output = BytesIO()
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter')
        
        # Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
        sample.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
        
        # Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
        workbook  = writer.book
        worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
        
        # Add a format.
        format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'red'})
        
        # Get the dimensions of the dataframe.
        (max_row, max_col) = sample.shape
        
        # Apply a conditional format to the required cell range.
        worksheet.conditional_format(1, 1, max_row, max_col,
                                    {'type':     'blanks',
                                    'format':   format1})
        
        # Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
        writer.save()
        
        xlsx_data = output.getvalue()
        
        blobService.create_blob_from_bytes(container_name,frolder_path_with_file_name, xlsx_data)
        ## Need to write xlsx_data to blob storage from here
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).